# How can I change/remove style attibute with selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium

I was wondering if it was possible to change or remove the "display: none;" in the element to make it visible with selenium in python.

```
<textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid #c1c1c1; margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none;  display: none; "></textarea>
```

I already tried this:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').style.display = '1';")
```

but apparently it does not work.

Any help would be apprreciated. :)

Comment: Try `style.display = 'block'` instead of `style.display = '1'`

Comment: @Andersson it worked ! Thank's !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was just the wrong CSS attribute, this works

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').style.display = 'block';")
```

Thanks to @Andersson