# Setting Style of Css in python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

This is my Code (without imports and stuff):

```
driver.get('http://democaptcha.com/demo-form-eng/hcaptcha.html')
time.sleep(3)
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByName('h-captcha-response').style.display='none';")
```

But this throws me the error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined

when i do:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('h-captcha-response-0zu3aawejggj').style.display = 'block';")
```

it shows me the error

> selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read property 'style' of null

(code is referenced to)

[Selenium (with python) how to modify an element css style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911980/selenium-with-python-how-to-modify-an-element-css-style)

[How can I change/remove style attibute with selenium python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47830954/how-can-i-change-remove-style-attibute-with-selenium-python)

THANKS!

Comment: `getElementsByName` returns an _array_ of elements, not one element. You can't do `getElementsByName().style`. An array has no `.style` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because it can't find the element. Probably because the `ID` keeps changing every page load. Another option could be

```
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector(`[id^='h-captcha-response']`).style.display = 'block'");
```

It means that it will find the first element with an `ID` that starts with `h-captcha-response`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByName('h-captcha-response')[0].style.display = 'block';")
```